# Having Problem with dynamically created UITextField in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitextfield

In my iphone app, I have created some UITextField in scrollView dynamically. And added one button in xib. On that button's TouchUpInside event, I opened UIImagePickercontroller to open photo library and taking selected image on UIImageView.

Now when modalview is dissmissed, values in my UITextField disappears.

How do I retain the UITextField values?

```
txt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 30.0f, 200.0f, 30.0f)];

[txt addTarget:self action:@selector(keyDown:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

txt.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;

txt.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

[fieldArray addObject:txt];
```

Using for loop I am adding txt to NSMutableArray fieldArray.

Here is the code where I fetch values from TextFields

```
NSMutableArray *insertValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//Taking values from textFields

for (int i=1; i<=nooffields; i++) {

    UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];

    NSLog(@"TF : %@",tf.text);

    if (tf.text.length<=0) {

        tf.text=@"";

    }

    [insertValues addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@'",tf.text]];
}
```

EDIT : 
And also when I display values from database in this textFields and try to edit it. It gives me null values.

What may be the reason? If there any other alternatives? please help me

Comment: post code. how do you create the uitextfield, how do you set the text, where does this text come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a work around for my problem.

I am temporarily storing my textField's values into database when presentModalViewController is called.

These values I retrieve back into the textFields on viewWillAppear.

This may not be a very efficient solution but it worked in my case.

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 3):

```
UITextField *textField=[[UITextField alloc]init];
[textField setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y, width, hight)];
[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

Answer (score 0):

The information that your scrollview uses to get populated should be stored outside the scrollview, in a `NSMutableDictionary` for example. So everytime `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called it can retrieve the information from that source. So I advise you to store the `UITextField`'s  text within the dictionary. You can index it by its tag number. That way you won't loose whatever it contained.

I hope it helps you

Cheers

Comment: This  is correct. Your views are most likely being redrawn right before the modal UIImagePickerController is fully dismissed. This will happen a lot of the time when running into low-memory situations. Not visible views will be dealloc'd and then re-initialized when the views come back into focus.

Comment: I am not using TableView. I got data from TextField once, but when I presentModalView to select image, then dissmiss that modal view, my textFields text set to blank.